# Sad and Melancholy yet Beautiful

Tags: single-word-requests, loanwords, archaicisms

I have been struggling to find a word that I, at one time, had seen in my vocabulary lessons. I am trying to describe something that is "beautiful or attractive" yet also possessing "sadness or melancholy." I think this word was most commonly used in the sense of describing a lady's face, where the poignant feature was seen as "beautifully sad."

I might say "the damsel's face showed lines of worry and stress, and her eyes dripped a touch. Her tousled hair and reddened skin made her a 'pathetic and beautiful' mess."

As much I try searching for this word, "pathetic" is the closest I've come to finding it. This word could be a borrowed one and potentially naturalized.

Comment: We millennials would call that "emo", though I am to believe that's not the kind of locution you're looking for.

Comment: Did a thesaurus suggest anything that combines both of those?

Comment: I haven’t found any entry of a thesaurus that combines both of these words yet.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'melancholic'?

Comment: My goodness,can we lose the damsel? Are you writing a book about the Middle Ages? pathetically beautiful **disarray** //disarray of pathos and beauty//beauty marred by disarray. etc. etc. You also might want to reconsider "her eyes dripped a touch" and "reddened skin". Try: glistening skin....dripping eyes and red skin are not exactly attractive features....

Answer (score 2):

Melancholy itself can describe this.  Sadness alone tends to imbue a sense of forlorn or general unhappiness.  Melancholy often rings with a sense of beauty or serenity in the face of sadness.

In Russian, Тоска (Toska) describes this in a way.  It's a very multifaceted and variant sadness that is often wrought with beauty.

Your initial "pathetic and beautiful mess" is actually really good, assuming that folk read pathetic literally rather than commonly. I can definitely envision that.

Answer (score 2):

Could the word you're looking for be wistfulness? I've actually been looking for the same word recently. Poignant is another one I saw recently.

Answer (score 0):

"mess" pretty much  deflates all lofty sentiment there. When the cat barfs on the kitchen floor it's a "mess", and  when a car drives through a puddle and splashes your suit you're a "mess".  I suppose you could call the "damsel" a ***forlorn*** mess.

The word **forlorn** can mean sad, in a pitiful way. A knight could ride up to   your damsel-in-distress and ask:

> Why so forlorn, lady?

Answer (score -1):

What about **[solemn](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/solemn)**:

1. characterized or marked by seriousness or sincerity: a solemn vow.
2. characterized by **pomp, ceremony**, or formality
3. serious, glum, or pompous
4. inspiring awe: a solemn occasion.
5. (Ecclesiastical Terms) performed with religious ceremony
6. **gloomy** or sombre: solemn colours.

Or **[pensive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pensive)**:

1. deeply or seriously thoughtful, often with a tinge of sadness

Comment: Pensive is a lovely choice. It would have to be given context for it to work well within a sentence, but it could work for my means. However, pensive is not the word that I am searching for. With the phrase “a pensive expression” there is no indication of beauty.

Answer (score -1):

The two salient descriptions you want to address (beauty and sadness) would seem to be in conflict, and there are many descriptive words for each. You might choose the words "**paradox**" or "**enigmatic**" in context to describe the two conflicting ideas. There would seem to be many possibilities using these words or something similar.

> "the damsel's face showed lines of worry and stress, and her eyes
>   dripped a touch. Her tousled hair and reddened skin made her a
>   '**paradox** of beauty'."

or

> "the damsel's face showed lines of worry and stress, and her eyes
>   dripped a touch. Her tousled hair and reddened skin framed her in a certain
>   '**enigmatic** beauty'."

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/paradox

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/enigma

Comment: Okay! I see how the words can be in conflict. I’m thinking the word was used in a much more poetic sense. I feel like the definitions you’ve given make me think of an “unknown” or “puzzling” beauty than something comparing beauty and melancholy. How would your words avoid that connotation?

Comment: Oh sorry, I've not much more to offer.  I have looked up several words - dolefulness and sonder and grace - for example. Each (poetic) word that I have wondered about is distinctly exclusive of the of the opposing qualities of sadness and/or beauty. The best that I found was "haunting" and "poignant".  Best of success though. https://www.thefreedictionary.com/poignant

Comment: One last thought - "evocative" covers all of the mixed emotions that your descriptive "she" engenders.

Answer (score -1):

Tristesse

Means a state of ongoing sadness.

And being French in origin, and pretty sounding, might do the job for your damsel.

How about:

*the damsel's face showed lines of worry and stress, and her eyes dripped a touch. Her messed-up hair and reddened skin made her a tousled portrait of tristesse.*

https://www.lexico.com/definition/tristesse